Map values set inside of a function not availabe in a different function
My NextJS server executes a function called "loadAllUserPools" during start up. Here's what the [abbreviated] file with this function looks like:
let userPoolMap = new Map();


export async function loadAllUserPools() {
  console.log('loadAllUserPools function started');
  // Triggered when the app starts. It gets all user pools
  // from the DB.

  // TODO: get data from db. Mocking DB data:
  const dbUserPoolData = [
    {
      cognitoUserPoolId: 'user-pool-1111111',
      cognitoClientId: '11111111111',
      accessUrl: 'tenant1',
    },
    {
      cognitoUserPoolId: 'user-pool-2222222',
      cognitoClientId: '222222222222',
      accessUrl: 'tenant2',
    },
  ];


  cognitoUserPoolList = [];

  // Update the cognitoVerifier list and the subdomain map
  dbUserPoolData.map((item) => {
    cognitoUserPoolList.push({
      userPoolId: item.cognitoUserPoolId,
      clientId: item.cognitoClientId,
      tokenUse: 'access',
    });
    userPoolMap.set(item.accessUrl, {
      userPoolId: item.cognitoUserPoolId,
      clientId: item.cognitoClientId,
    });
  });
  console.log('map: ', userPoolMap);
}

export async function getCognitoUserPoolBySubdomain(subdomain: string) {
  console.log('map: ', userPoolMap);
  const data = userPoolMap.get(subdomain);
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

When the "loadAllUserPools" function executes, it prints the Map to the console with the expected values, which tells me that the map values are being properly set:
loadAllUserPools function started
map:  Map(2) {
  'tenant1' => { userPoolId: 'user-pool-1111111', clientId: '11111111111' },
  'tenant2' => { userPoolId: 'user-pool-2222222', clientId: '222222222222' }
}

Later when a user tries to login, I invoke the "getCognitoUserPoolBySubdomain" function, which tries to get a value from the Map. However, the map returns "undefined" when trying to find "tenant1". Furthermore, printing the Map to the console shows a Map length of zero:
getCognitoUserPoolBySubdomain function started
map:  Map(0) {}
undefined

Any ideas on why the "getCognitoUserPoolBySubdomain" function can't see the values that were previously set in the Map?

Why is loadAllUserPools declared async? It never uses await.

In the real version, is it calling an async API to get the user data? I suspect you're not waiting for this to complete before calling getCognitoUserPoolBySubdomain(). Make sure you use await loadAllUserPools().

I suspect this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

@Barmar I declared it as async because later I'm going to add some code to retrieve some data (dbUserPoolData) from a DB. As for calling the getCognitoUserPoolBySubdomain() function, that is happening much later when I try to login with a frontend login form. I'm reading up on the Stackflow link you provided.

In that case I can't see any reason why it's not working. Something else must be overwriting the Map.

That link is only relevant if you try to read the map immediately after calling the async function.

@Barmar that was my first thought too (getting overwritten), but those are the only references to the "userPoolMap" in the entire application. It should be so simple, but I really don't understand why it is not working...

Is it possible you're importing the module multiple times?

Try putting console.log("userPoolMap initialzed"); after let userPoolMap = new Map();, do you see this multiple times?

Aside: It's not related to the problem, but use .forEach() rather than .map() when you don't need an array of the results.

@Barmar You are right! The module is being initialized multiple times (it contains other functions used by different components). Let me see if I can refactor this to avoid the reloading of the map.

Try changing it to let userPoolMap; if (!userPoolMap) { userPoolMap = new Map(); }

@Barmar Typescript didn't like that last recommendation, but reformatting things a bit took care of it. I moved the loadAllUserPools functionality to a separate file (loadUserPools.ts). The new file just saves the user pools into a regular constant, which is later exported by a "getUserPools" function. Then all I have to do is invoke that last function from somewhere else. This pattern is similar to how we define a single database instance. It now makes sense to me. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Is cognitoUserPoolList some global variable or did you just forget to declare it in your example code?

"Is it possible you're importing the module multiple times" - if it's the same module, it won't get initialised multiple times. Even if imported multiple times, the module is shared. This could only happen if the program is run in multiple times, or in workers or serverless or something…
